# Способ задания ключевых слов

Tags: c#, c++

Необходимо парсить файл на ключевые слова. Ключевых слов небольшое количество.

Хотелось бы узнать как именовать ключевые слова правильно и что желательно красиво. Есть ли способ обращения по имени переменной в виде строки, или задать строку без типа данных.

Хотелось бы избежать такого объявления.

```
const string NAME {NAME};
//////////////////// или
const string NAME; 
labelname.Text = nameof(NAME);
```

Comment: Чем вас `nameof()` не устроил?

Comment: При чем тут файл?

Comment: О чём вообще речь?

Comment: Как измерить красоту?

Comment: Очень зависит от вашего языка. Например, в C поиск подстрок в тексте не даст нужного результата, т. к. есть комментарии и строковые литералы.

Answer (score 0):

А в данном случае enum не лучше использовать?

```
    enum FullName
    {
        Name,
        LastName
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FullName fullName;
        fullName = FullName.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(fullName); // > Name

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```